# What is meant by "Staging Upload"

Tags: maven, nexus

To upload an artifact to Nexus I'm following this guide :

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/using-sect-uploading.html

To access the upload page :

[image]

I click "Staging Upload" from Nexus dashboard :

[image]

What is meant by "Staging Upload" ? Does this mean I need to promote it when uploaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The staging feature of Nexus allows you to test changes. For example, you can upload a huge project, then test if everything is OK and finally, you can promote the result to make it permanent.

Without staging, things can get ugly. Imagine you have a new release of a product and you deploy this to Nexus. Five minutes later, someone finds a little problem. Without staging, you now have two options:

1. Delete the deployed files manually and pray that you don't make a mistake
2. Bump all version numbers of your release and release it again and pray that the problem is now fixed or you'll have to do this again.